# My functions error when I try to call them. Can someone have a look?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the function to call but it throws the error:

```
add_entrance(entrances)
NameError: name 'entrances' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would like to assume it is the same for all the functions where I have imported something from somewhere else that has been returned.
Any tips on what I've done wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
import time
def add_entrance(entrances):
    if entrances == 501:
        print("Sorry but the park is currently at maximum capacity, we are sorry for any inconvenience.")
        welcome()
        return entrances
```

Comment: `add_entrance(entrances)` means "retrieve the variable `entrances`, retrieve the function `add_entrance` and apply that function to the value of `entrances`". `NameError: name 'entrances' is not defined` is telling you that the first step failed because there is no variable called `entrances`.

Comment: You should pass to the function a value to work with. You hav no variable called ```entrances```. Read about [Function Arguments](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_arguments.asp).

Comment: BTW, since you're a beginner you might like some advice. You're not writing structured code. Define all classes and functions at the beginning of your program. Don't mix them with other top-level code. Don't define functions in functions until you understood the basics of programming and know when this might be a good idea. Don't use functions as points to jump to. You're using functions as if you want to emulate `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are trying to send an argument to your function that is undefined.

Your function will take a number as input , or a defined variable i.e.

```
entrances = 1
```

and then call the function.

you could also just call the function as

```
add_entrances(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function, you pass a value to this function. sometimes you pass a variable that stores this value, so in

```
add_entrance(entrances)
NameError: name 'entrances' is not defined
```

you pass the value stored in the a variable `entrances`, but you did not define that varaible, so you should define it first

```
entrances = the_value_you want
add_entrance(entrances)
```

That is all.